# How to buffer / preload html5 videos using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, buffer

I am running the following code which changes the source of an html5 video at the end of each video, so that it constantly plays one video after another. After the first video finishes, it runs the second, then the third and eventually starts again from the beginning, resulting in an endless cycle. It also chooses a random starting point, but that is not important for my question.

In the code below you will only find two video sources but the final code would use around ten or so.

My problem is that there is a small pause between the end of a video and the beginning of the next one. I have made the background-color of the video tag red so that you will be able to see a red flash between the playback of each video.

I'm guessing that this could be solved by preloading all videos specified inside the javascript code. So what I would like to achieve is to preload only the next video in the list specified inside the javascript code when the current video is playing. So when video nr. 5 is playing, it should preload video nr. 6 etc..

Or is this not something that could be solved by effective buffering / preloading? I'm happy about any other suggestions as well..

```js
var vidElement = document.getElementById('video');
    var vidSources = [
      "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
      "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
      ];
    var activeVideo = Math.floor((Math.random() * vidSources.length));
    vidElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
    vidElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
      // update the active video index
      activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % vidSources.length;
      if(activeVideo === vidSources.length){
        activeVideo = 0;
      }

      // update the video source and play
      vidElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
      vidElement.play();
    });
```

```css
video { background-color: red }
```

```html
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="video" autoplay muted playsinline></video>
<p>(each video is just ~ 10 seconds)</p>
```

Comment: Would you like to have preloaded an entire HTML5 video source or only a small part?

Comment: @Bharata Whatever helps to get rid of the red flash (small gap) in between the videos.. I was guessing that preloading each video prior to playback would solve this but I’m not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `video` elements with `preload` attribute and add it to div containar like follows:

```js
function initVideoElement(videoEl)
{
    videoEl.playsinline = true;
    videoEl.muted = false;
    videoEl.preload = 'auto'; //but do not set autoplay, because it deletes preload

    //loadedmetadata is wrong because if we use it then we get endless loop
    videoEl.onplaying = function(e)
    {
        if(++nextActiveVideo == 2)
            nextActiveVideo = 0;

        //replace the video elements against each other:
        if(this.inx == 0)
            nextVideoElement = videoElements[1];
        else
            nextVideoElement = videoElements[0];

        nextVideoElement.src = vidSources[nextActiveVideo];
        nextVideoElement.pause();
    };

    videoEl.onended = function(e)
    {
        this.style.display = 'none';
        nextVideoElement.style.display = 'block';
        nextVideoElement.play();
    };
}

var videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer'),
    nextActiveVideo = 0,
    nextVideoElement,
    videoElements =
    [
        document.createElement('video'),
        document.createElement('video')
    ],
    vidSources =
    [
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
    ];

videoElements[0].inx = 0; //set index
videoElements[1].inx = 1;

initVideoElement(videoElements[0]);
initVideoElement(videoElements[1]);

videoElements[0].autoplay = true;
videoElements[0].src = vidSources[0];
videoContainer.appendChild(videoElements[0]);

videoElements[1].style.display = 'none';
videoContainer.appendChild(videoElements[1]);
```

```css
video{background-color: red}
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer"></div>
```

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann, did you not seen this snippet? Instead of autoplay I use play() and it works. Or what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I did see it but I need a solution that works with autoplay.. Could you perhaps create a jsFiddle of this that uses autplay? I'm also looking into other solutions that create a canvas instead of a video tag similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34137680/1517585

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann, I do not understand why do yo need autoplay when it works with play()? Your next video starts automaticalľy. What do you need more? Or do you need that your first video starts automaticalľy? If yes you can write `vidElement.setAttribute('autoplay','true');` direct after creating from `vidElement`. You can read **[in the docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload)** the following: _The autoplay attribute has precedence over preload. If autoplay is specified, the browser would obviously need to start downloading the video for playback._

Comment: Yes, I need that the first video starts automatically. I have inserted the code as you suggested and everything works fine, but the small gap inbetween the videos is visible just like with my own solution I posted in the question (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/zwnjbt1L/) 
I have set the background-color of the video to red so that this gap is clearly visible. 

So this is basically what I had already achieved anyway when posting the question. What I wanted to achieve was to have both autoplay AND effective preloading so that the small gap would disappear...

Comment: With the current solutions, preloading is not effectively used when using autoplay, because it can only start preloading as soon as the playback of the next video starts.. instead, it should already do that while the current video is still playing.

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann, your jsfiddle example is wrong because I wrote that you have to set `autoplay` direct after creating from `vidElement`. But you have replaced `preload` with `autoplay` in `createVideoElement()`. Anyway, I have changed my code and it works now like you it need (hopefully).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Unfortunately, this somehow crashes my browsers after a short while. I've tried with chrome and firefox. I need to check on another computer to see if I am the only one experiencing this problem..

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann, the browser crashing is because of `canplay` bug by some browsers. I have forgotten about it. But now I have replaced `canplay` with `loadedmetadata` and it should work without any problems.

Comment: Yes this seems to work so I will mark your answer as the correct answer but it somehow still seems to be quite heavy for the browser.. I have also tested on my other laptop and I always see it laggingwhen playing the video with the bear.

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann, today is your lucky day – I have solved the problem with endless loop overload (_but it somehow still seems to be quite heavy for the browser_)  after long trying (a lot of time). Now you can upvote my answer, if you like it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I see youre now switching between the videos by toggling the display state - thats clever!